# Both Fragments Visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have read a lot of good info here and made good progress, but am now stuck. My Android project in its current state consists of a ViewPager with two navigation tabs built with Action Bar Sherlock. One tab is a ListFragment and the other is currently just a Fragment for testing purposes. I would like to replace the ListFragment with a details Fragment in the same container as the ListFragment rather than opening a new activity. I am able to do this, using a layout suggested in this forum (without the FrameLayout wrapper I cannot get the details to load):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use a callback to the main Activity when a list item is clicked.

From the ListFragment:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)  {
    mCallback.onItemSelected(position);     
}
```

And in the main Activity:

```
public void onItemSelected(int position)  {     

    TestDetailsFragment newFragment = new TestDetailsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.main_container, newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();        
}
```

And finally, my TestDetailsFragment:

```
public class TestDetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

}

My problem is that the ListFragment remains visible when the details fragment is loaded.  If I press "back", the details text goes away. And if I do not press back, but swipe to my other Fragment, the details text remains. I think if I could change the **ft.replace(R.id.main_container, newFragment);** to **ft.replace(R.id.*containerId of ViewPager page*, newFragment)** it would work, but I cannot figure out how to do that despite much searching. I tried replacing the list layout the following way, which also did not work (error: no view found for *my_list_layout*): **ft.replace(R.id.my_list_layout, newFragment);**  Here is the XML for the ListFragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_list_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

I'm really new at this (my first post on here), so I will go ahead and put my entire main activity here in case I am missing something really obvious. Thank you!

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
        implements MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener  {

ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_title);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("tab1"), MyFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("tab2"), MyListFragment.class, null);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)  {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }        
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

public void onItemSelected(int position)  {     

    TestDetailsFragment newFragment = new TestDetailsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_container, newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();        
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener  {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();


    static final class TabInfo  {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)  {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()  {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)  {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
            int positionOffsetPixels)  {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected (int position)  {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)  {          
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)  {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)  {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++)  {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag)  {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override 
    public void onTabUnselected (Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)  {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected (Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)  {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the ListFragment remains visible when the details
>   fragment is loaded

That is normal as your code for replacing the fragments between them puts the new details fragment in the `FrameLayout` which also contains your `ViewPager`(with the corresponding `ListFragment`), which will not be removed.

> I think if I could change the ft.replace(R.id.main_container,
>   newFragment); to ft.replace(R.id.containerId of ViewPager page,
>   newFragment) it would work, but I cannot figure out how to do that
>   despite much searching.

Yes this would be an option. I recommend that you use the new nested `Fragments` API(available with the compatibility package or the normal `Fragments`, API 16+). If you want to just replace the `ListFragment` with the new details `Fragment`(so you keep that extra `Fragment` of the `ViewPager` + the ability to swipe to it) then do this:

- where you currently use the `ListFragment` you'll put a simple wrapper `Fragment`(which has as a layout a simple `FrameLayout`), the other `Fragment` of the `ViewPager` will remain untouched
- at start use the `getChildFragmentManager()` in the wrapper `Fragment` to add the normal `ListFragment`
- make the wrapper fragment implement your callback interface. To get a reference to the parent `Fragment` you can use the `getParentFragment()` method in the `ListFragment` and cast this as your listener
- in the callback that the wrapper `Fragment` will implement, replace the `ListFragment` with the details `Fragment` using the `FrameLayout`.

If you want the details `Fragment` to replace the `ViewPager`(with it's two fragments together) then modify the layout of the `Activity` to have only a `FrameLayout` to which you'll add either a `Fragment` which contains the `ViewPager` or the details `Fragment`.